# Relacionamento tabelas localStorage Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, ionic2, angular, ionic3, localstorage

Quero fazer um relacionamento entre duas "tabelas" no Ionic 3 com LocalSotrage.

Criei um provider com o primeiro que seria o cadastro de movimentos:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';


@Injectable()
export class MovimentoProvider {

  lista:any[];
  chave:string = "movimentos";


  constructor(private storage: Storage) {
    this.storage.ready().then(()=>{
      this.storage.get(this.chave).then((registros) => {
        if(registros){
          this.lista= registros;
        }else{
          this.lista=[];
        }
      });      
    });

  }

  listar(){
    return this.lista;
  }

  cadastrar(registro:any){    
    this.storage.ready().then(()=>{
      this.lista.push(registro);
      this.storage.set(this.chave, this.lista);
    })
    }


    deletar(registro){
      for(let chave in this.lista){
        if(this.lista[chave] == registro){
          this.lista.splice(parseInt(chave),1);
          this.storage.set(this.chave, this.lista);
        }        
      }
    }

    atualizar(movimento,registro){ 
      for(let chave in this.lista){
        if(this.lista[chave] == movimento){
          this.lista[chave] = registro;
          this.storage.set(this.chave, this.lista);
        }
      }

    }



}
```

Criei um "controller" para este cadastro:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MovimentoProvider } from '../../providers/movimento/movimento'
import { MovimentosPage } from '../movimentos/movimentos';

/**
 * Generated class for the MovimentoTipoEditPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

interface IMovimento{
  nome:string;
  tipo:string;
}

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-movimento-tipo-edit',
  templateUrl: 'movimento-tipo-edit.html',
})

export class MovimentoTipoEditPage {

  movimento:IMovimento = {nome:'', tipo:''};
  movimentos:IMovimento[];  
  movimentoEditando:IMovimento;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public MovimentoProvider:MovimentoProvider) {
    this.movimento = this.navParams.get('dados');
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad MovimentoTipoEditPage');
  }

  atualizar(movimento){    
    if(this.movimento.nome != "" && this.movimento.tipo != ""){   
      this.movimento = {nome:movimento.nome,tipo:movimento.tipo};   
      this.movimentoEditando = movimento;
      this.MovimentoProvider.atualizar(this.movimentoEditando,this.movimento);    
      this.navCtrl.push(MovimentosPage);
    }
    //this.movimento = {nome:movimento.nome, tipo:movimento.tipo}
    //this.movimentoEditando = movimento;

  }

  cancelar(movimento:IMovimento){

  }


}
```

E sua View bem simples:

```
<!--
  Generated template for the MovimentoTiposPage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
-->
<ion-header>

    <ion-navbar color="dark">
        <button ion-button menuToggle>
          <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <ion-title>Tipos de Movimentos</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

    <ion-list>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Nome do Movimento</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="movimento.nome"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Tipo de Movimento</ion-label>
            <ion-select [(ngModel)]="movimento.tipo">
                <ion-option value="Distância">Distância</ion-option>
                <ion-option value="Repetições">Repetições</ion-option>
                <ion-option value="Peso">Peso</ion-option>
                <ion-option value="Altura">Altura</ion-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-item>


    </ion-list>



    <button ion-button full (click)="atualizar(movimento)">Atualizar</button>
    <button ion-button full (click)="cancelar()">Cancelar</button>

</ion-content>
```

Agora tenho que criar um novo provider que seria os tempos de cada movimento e deve ser de acordo com o ID do registro selecionado pelo usuário. Como posso fazer este relacionamento por LocalStorage?

Comment: Você realmente precisa de um mapeamento relacional pra isso? Se cada Tempo que você precisa cadastrar é relativo a um Movimento, você poderia simplesmente criar a estrutura como um único objeto. Onde Movimento possui 1:n (ou 1:1 n sei...) tempos.. Dessa forma você não precisa se preocupar com a complexidade de persistir e manter esses relacionamentos (o que seria mais correto utilizar o SQLite diretamente).

Comment: Assim, você manter um array de movimentos no storage. e quando houver um update você substitui o objeto no indice x pela sua versão atualizada e atualiza seu Storage.

Comment: Se você realmente quiser manter a estrutura relacional de tabelas pra esse problema, sugiro dar uma olhada no TypeORM (https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm)